# Cannot open database ''. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt

Tags: c#, .net, database, ado.net, oledb

I have the following connection string using ado.net

> String ConectionString=@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=D:\Data.accdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mypassword;"

I faced the problem 
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered on local Machine

I solved it By installing 64 version of the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010.
And edit Build Properties to x 86
But it never worked so I had to install 2007 Office System Driver :Data Connectivity components 
When I installed the last one the problem disappeared 
But I faced a new problem

Additional information: Cannot open database ''. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.

That is my problem now any help please?
The three solutions I followed are found in this amazing video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzLA_z7tDPs

sorry i forgot the most important information which is i am using Microsoft office plus 2013 and i installed `AccessRuntime_x64_en-us` for office 2013 but it never works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue and I solved it right now.

The solution is to **build a new Database by using the new version of Office we have**.

Also you should **install (Microsoft Access Database Engine)** that has no. of bits (32 or 64) just like your Office and everything will work.