# Cannot connect to password encrypted MS Access 2016 database using C#

Tags: c#, database, encryption, ms-access-2016

When I try to connect to a MS Access 2016 database, it connects perfectly without password, but when I try to connect to the same database after encrypting it with a password, I get this error:

> Cannot open the database. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.

I don't know what I should do - my database isn't corrupted, and I have to make it with a password. Is there a way to do it, or am I wrong in something?

File extension is `.accdb`

Screenshots:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vhp7pID4iQ_zoc6ImWXoJDFQv10qNRRn

https://drive.google.com/open?id=18QbuFhDU11YuYS-Pe1jxxIhtLPeff-lC

Comment: post your connection string here

Comment: @Sachith i don't use connection string i'm connecting with data server in visual and uploaded 2 photos.

Comment: Did you install `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable`?

Comment: yes i have installed it the database works without password the only problem is when i encrypt it with password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope your connection string as follows,

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[Path];Jet OLEDB:Database Password=[Password];"
```

So, you used `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver` and must be installed on your machine, as it doesn't come with windows. you can find the driver on this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

And hope this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301273/cannot-open-database-it-may-not-be-a-database-that-your-application-recogniz?rq=1) also help to you. and also [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e01fe29-5abe-4620-976a-225510b5017a/how-to-connect-to-encrypted-or-password-protected-msaccess-db?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)

How to use access connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: Probem solved after uinstalling AccessDatabaseEngine 64 and installing AccessDatabaseEngine 32 thank you !.