# Problem to connect to MS Access 2016 database has password

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I try to connect to a MS Access 2016 database, it connects perfectly without password, but when I try to connect to the same database after encrypting it with a password, I get this error:

> Cannot open the database. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.

here is my code:

```
ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
              Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SCLogin.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123"
```

Comment: Your connection string works, so the problem is somewhere else.  File locked by another process?  Is the file actually there?  Is it a valid database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to password encrypted MS Access 2016 database using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117757/cannot-connect-to-password-encrypted-ms-access-2016-database-using-c-sharp)

Comment: So you added the Jet OLEDB part and it doesn't work? Not sure but shouldn't that be `ACE OLEDB:` to match the provider?

Comment: @CharlesMay [Access connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

Comment: I used already but there is no successful result

Answer (score 1):

In Access; try options and choose an earlier encryption method like 2007 encryption method.  Newer encryption methods may not work with the provider.  It might be called "Use Legacy Encryption".

Comment: Hi Chris,I made the change but still getting the same problem :) 
 do you have other idea?
 thank you

Comment: The only other things I can think of is some reports of problems with passwords longer than 14 characters. Also that some characters might cause trouble. If you are having problems, try change password to a short one with normal characters.  I know you have "123" for the password in your example but maybe you are using a more complicated on in your production?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the solution Chris offed would work.  Hummm....try C&R.  That often fixes weird issues with Access.

The connection string should look like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/